# O or L after 3 clock pulses VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I need a help to solve a codelock-problem on VHDL.

Open-lamp high after 3 sequences 100,101,110
otherwise Lock-lamp high. 
Every sequence feeds in with a clock pulse.
Lamps are high only with third infeeded sequence.
Reset-key should help to reset the process.

Thanks aLot.

```
process (R, clk, X, S1, S2, S3) begin 
if R = '1' then 
 O <= '0'; 
 L <= '0'; 
elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then 
 if X = "100" then 
  S1 <= '1'; 
  if X = "101" then 
   S2 <= '1'; 
  else S2 <= '0'; 
   if X = "110" then 
    S3 <= '1'; 
   else 
    S3 <= '0'; 
   end if; 
  end if;
  else S1 <= '0'; 
 end if; 
end if; 
if S1 = '1' and S2 = '1' and S3 = '1' then 
 O <= '1'; 
 L <= '0'; 
elsif S1 = '0' and S2 = '0' and S3 = '0' then 
 O <= '0'; 
 L <= '1'; 
end if; 
end process; 
end behavioral;
```

Comment: You need to show some code. What have you tried?

Comment: process (R, clk, X, S1, S2, S3)
 begin 
  if R = '1' then
   O <= '0';
   L <= '0';
  elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
   if X = "100" then
    S1 <= '1';
    if X = "101" then
     S2 <= '1';
    else 
     S2 <= '0';
      if X = "110" then
       S3 <= '1';
   
      else 
       S3 <= '0';
       
      end if;
    end if;
   else 
    S1 <= '0';
   end if;
   
  end if;
  if S1 = '1' and S2 = '1' and S3 = '1' then
   O <= '1';
   L <= '0';
  elsif S1 = '0' and S2 = '0' and S3 = '0' then
   O <= '0';
   L <= '1';
  end if;
 end process;

end behavioral;

Comment: What is the observed problem?

Comment: The O- and P- lamps light even when I feed in just 2 sequences, they don't wait untill third one.

Comment: And the O- and P- lamps are connected to?   X is driven by?

Comment: Write a testbench and simulate your code. It's a waste of time to try to debug by inspection when you can directly observe what's happening.

Comment: Lamps are connected, but I control the x.

Comment: I can nothing about testbench :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first suggestion from my end is to break up the code into 2 processes. Process 1 should be a state machine which you have tried to implement in the earlier half of the code with signals S1, S2 & S3. Process 2 should be used to drive the output lamps. 
Here are a few suggestions which you could implement in the code to make it working:

1. Initialize S1, S2 & S3 to '0' initially and also whenever reset R is applied.
2. For each condition of X which you are checking with if statement, add an else statement too. For example,

   ```
                  if X = "100" then
                    S1 <= '1';
                  else
                    S1 <= '0';
                  end if;
   ```
3. Modify each subsequent condition for the next states such that the previous state is also considered. i.e, 
                      if S1 = '1' and X = "101" then
                        S2 <= '1';
                      else
                        S2 <= '0';
                      end if;
   like that.
   This could be one reason why your lamps started glowing before the sequence was completed.

Once the state machine is properly coded in process 1, then you can decide how you want your lamp control logic to work here. You are free to use combinatorial logic coding or sequential coding (using another process) for this purpose. I would prefer to drive the O-lamp with a 3-input combinatorial AND gate as given below:
O <= S1 and S2 and S3;

This ensures that any change in state of S1/S2/S3 is immediately reflected in the lamp without any clock pulse delay.

Try simulating the code once in ModelSim or any other simulators to see if it is working fine now.